# Word wrap in verbatim environments

Tags: latex

I noticed that LaTeX's `verbatim` environment doesn't do word wrapping. How do I get it to word wrap verbatim text?

Comment: A better place for LaTeX questions is http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Essentially you can’t.

But the `listings` package, whose actual purpose is to format source code, does support word wrapping. So maybe you can use the `listings` environment instead.

Comment: For the sake of reference, I'll just post this here... You can enable word wrapping in `listings` like this: `\lstset{breaklines=true}`. The environment you'll wanna use is `lstlisting`. More at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings.

Comment: Sorry down vote because code was line wrapped but not formatted as code.

Comment: @Tasawer What are you talking about? `listings` *does* format the code. If it isn’t formatted for you then you did something wrong. You probably just didn’t configure it properly. Did you read the `listings` documentation? Did you try figuring out what’s wrong? Or did you prefer to just complain?

Comment: Just to clarify @Pieter's point, for those new LaTeX users (read:me). `\usepackage{listings}` must be added and \lstset{breaklines=true} as well.  Lastly, you must not use the `\verbatim` tag, but rather `\begin{lstlisting}`.

Comment: The listings package does not support UTF-8.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the full example for the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true} 

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
some text here
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

You might also add the following definitions for *line numbering* and _background_color:

```
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, numbersep=10pt, captionpos=b} 
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{gray-5}}
\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}
\lstset{framesep=4pt}
```

Add this for inline code:

```
\newcommand{\inlineCode}{\lstinline[basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily]}
```